# How to replace content of a file in java?

Tags: java, file, serialization, file-io

I am writing data to a file using an ObjectOutputStream. I have a class Data which implements Serializable interface. This class has 4 instance variables. I am successfully able to write data to the file and also read it.

When the user changes any one of the instance variable of this class, I have to write all 4 variables to the file once again. Is there a solution to this such that instead of writing all four variable to the file, I just replace the data of the variable that has been changed?

Here is the some of the code:

```
public class Data implements Serializable{
     int i, j;
     String s1, s2;
```

}

Comment: No. It would mean "hacking" the object stream. I advice is to not go there.

Comment: Do you have to store serialized objects? Why not just map to a database or a key-value store?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `Serializable` you could look at `Externalizable` which would give you control over the way you write the serialized data -- so you could in fact if you want say serialize your object to CSV-like format. If you couple this with a diff mechanism (compare the line generated from the previous state the line that from the current state you could then use a `RandomAccessFile` and only write the differences.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only serializing instances of your class you could just choose your own binary representation and implement methods to store/load objects. However, if you are using this "Data" class as part of e.g. Java-collections and gets serialized as part of those what you need is custom serialization, have a look here:

```
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/
```

Under the heading:

```
Customize the Default Protocol
```